# Build Azure deployment package in NAnt

Tags: .net, build, azure, cloud, nant

I'm looking into migrating our system to Windows Azure. Currently we have an automated process that builds everything and packages it up into msi's for us using Team City and NAnt.

Is there any way to build the packages needed for deployment - I don't need it to deploy, just create the package.

Thanks

Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is straight forward to add some commands to your NANT file to package your application.

See this page for examples and a reference:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432988.aspx

Comment: Thanks to all three (they certainly look like they'll work), but I try to avoid MSBuild as it's a little bit too 'Visual Studio Magical' for me and I like things as simple as I can make them. This looks like exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

There is: with MSBuild

```
 msbuild AzureProject.ccproj /target:publish /p:Configuration=Release;TargetProfile=ReleaseProfile
```

will create an Azure package using the "Release" configuration and "ReleaseProfile" Azure profile.

Note, if your Azure project is in a solution folder (say "folder") you'll need e.g.

```
 msbuild folder\AzureProject.ccproj /target:publish /p:Configuration=Release;TargetProfile=ReleaseProfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
<echo message="Publishing Azure Package"/>
<exec program="${MSBuildPath}" workingdir="${BuildDirectory}" commandline="Products\SportsCommanderV3\SportsCommanderCloudService\SportsCommanderCloudService.ccproj /t:CorePublish /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutDir=${ReleaseDirectory}\${BuildLabel}\Azure\"/>
```

The OurDir part used to publish the package over to a release directory on our server, but as of the Azure 1.5 SDK that seemed to stop working, so now I add this:

```
    <copy todir="${ReleaseDirectory}\${BuildLabel}\Azure\Publish">
        <fileset basedir="${BuildDirectory}\Products\SportsCommanderV3\SportsCommanderCloudService\bin\Release\app.publish">
            <include name="**/*"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
```